# GetTopLevelResources: null

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

In my application written in xamarin for android, I am setting the language based on configuration setting from the server on each screen as it loads like this:

```
var res = Resources;
var config = res.Configuration;
config.Locale = new Java.Util.Locale(INConstant.Language);
var displayMetrics = res.DisplayMetrics;
res.UpdateConfiguration(config, displayMetrics);
```

This works ok on almost all of the devices, but on some I get error:

```
W/ResourcesManager( 3315): getTopLevelResources: null for user  0
```

Which affects setting language and playing media files from the resources. I didn't find any solution on to why this could be the problem only on some phones like: **SM-G361F Galaxy Core Prime**

Does anyone have any idea on why is this happening?